# Elegant method to find next pixel in line

Tags: c++, sorting, line, pixel

I'm following a one pixel line which sometimes intersects with other lines, and I'm trying to find an elegant way to stay on the same line.

[image: line example] [image: line example2]

The current pixel is `0` (blue). the previous pixel is `-1` (black).

In the first image there are two possible next pixels (green and red) but the green pixel (`1`) should be chosen because it continues the line.

In the second image there are two green pixels (`1`) which I'd be equally happy with - I don't mind leaving the choice between them undefined as long as it's not the red one.

In pseudo-cpp:

```
vector<Point> points;

for (i = x - 1; i < x + 2; i++) {
    for (j = y - 1; j < y + 2; j++) {
        if (i == x && j == y) {
            continue;
        }

        if (IS_ON(i, j) && NOT_VISITED(i, j)) {
            points.push_back(Point(i, j));
        }
    }
}

// sort points to find closest to opposite lastX,lastY

lastX = x;
lastY = y;

x = points[0].x;
y = points[0].y;
```

The sorting step is the bit I'm struggling with.

I was thinking of using std::sort but I'm having a hard time formulating the comparison function.

What would the appropriate comparison function look like, or is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: I haven't thought this through much at all, but how about just choosing the pixel farthest away from the last pixel?

Comment: your problem description is ill-formed or you did not give all information. Chosing any of the 1 pixels in the right image is not a line anymore unless you define a start/endpoint and use something like bresenham to walk through that line. Steps occur then due to rasterization (i.e. aliasing).
Is your slope always 1? If yes, then neither of the 1's are on your line. What happens when both 1's are missing in the right image? is the red pixel your "best bet"? But then you are following a curve and not a line.

Comment: @Bwmat You're right, I was overcomplicating this by considering the current pixel. The furthest pixel away from the previous pixel is all I need, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If currentP=(x,y) is your current point, lastP is the previous point, then test all possible points p by taking the dot product

> (currentP-lastP)*(p-currentP)

and choose the p with the biggest dot product. See wikipedia for dot product.